# ORM RedBeanPHP двойной запрос

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Здравствуйте
есть таблица messages в которой есть 2 поля sender и addressee в которых хранятся ID отправителя и ID получателя

делаю первый запрос:

```
$sender = R::findAll('messages', 'sender = ?', ['32']);
```

делаю второй запрос

```
$addressee = R::findAll('messages', 'addressee = ?', ['35']);
```

Получаю 2 выборки с БД

Подскажите как объединить эти 2 запроса или посоветуйте правильную реализацию на основе ORM RedBeanPHP

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Comment: https://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/finding_beans пример 2

Comment: во первых это старая документация, а во вторых документацию я могу и сам прочить, но я попросил помощи в реализации в не ссылку на документацию. Спасибо

Comment: Там показано, как использовать подстановку нескольких параметров. Вместо скалярного аргумента используется массив. Сомневаюсь, что в этом моменте что-то поменялось. Попробуйте что-нибудь типа `R::findAll('messages', 'sender = ? addressee = ?', ['32','35']);`.